# Remember me cookie decoding process

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me

I am using spring remember me services. I am seeing a strange behavior.

Steps I am taking:

- login to my website using username /password and checking the remember me checkbox
- than I am closing the browser and opening a new browser and opening a new browser. Technically I must login automatically . This is also happening. I am using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`.
- Now I close the browser again and opening a new browser again and when I try to access my website I am getting the following exception:

  ```
      SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/Spring-Security] threw exception org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:102)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:115)
      at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
      at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
      at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
      at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
  ```

  I drilled down more and i saw for my last two request the remember me token `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE` the value was

  bUpwUUJ3dGpUcVJjaGpIYXJxcmFkdz09OlBBRlZXbDVnYmZZQjM2RmFYVDNVMXc9PQ

but spring decoded the (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.tokenRepository)

```
    final String presentedSeries = cookieTokens[0];
    final String presentedToken = cookieTokens[1];
```

correctly in first request but in second requested it decoded presentedToken  something different resulting in cookie theft exception .

Is this the right behavior? How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: It seams that the `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeService` allways create a new token when a user login via cookie.

So there must be different cookie values for the 2. und 3. Login. - Check that your Browser send different cookie values.

Comment: I checked the browser sends the same cookie every time.The SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE was MWJ0cmc0SGxFelJzcStXUmhsaVhtUT09OjI0cWlVcHk1Q2QrWVJTb2hKZU1BNmc9PQ i checked with firebug.

Comment: I check for the same cookie the following line String cookieAsPlainText = new String(Base64.decode(cookieValue.getBytes()));is creating different values. This is strange... . This line is in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.decodeCookie(String) method.

Comment: Do you agree that `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` line 120 and 121 create a new token after each successfull login? `tokenRepository.updateToken(newToken.getSeries(), newToken.getTokenValue(), newToken.getDate());
            addCookie(newToken, request, response);` - put a beak point in this line and see what happens

Comment: Oops !!!!Actually i made a mistake in looking minutely. The three stage cookie are as follows bDc0TzR2QnRXdFhhbXNQTlR6ZHRLQT09OkFWbUNqcDkxczQyNnJQUjZvKzNIOXc9PQ

bDc0TzR2QnRXdFhhbXNQTlR6ZHRLQT09OkFWbUNqcDkxczQyNnJQUjZvKzNIOXc9PQ

bDc0TzR2QnRXdFhhbXNQTlR6ZHRLQT09Om9zZ3FoRWpLeDRrUHhDTlFsTmVoUkE9PQ the last cookie differs from the first two. How i can get the same cookie or handle this on spring side.

Comment: Does the same problem occure if you NEVER have two Brower instances at the same time?

Comment: Okay the problem is resolved. Thanks ralph. Your point regarding update token was very good because i saw the update was not working properly. Now i rectified the mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.
The first request was matching the token and then creating a new token however immediately after this a second request would arrive (with the same token as the first request) and the tokens would no longer match!

I could not work out why the second request was coming in straight after the first.

In the end my solution was to subclass `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` and overrode the `processAutoLoginCookie` method. I simply commented out the check for the cookie theft exception **(this creates a security hole, however it was acceptable for my purposes)**.

If you want a more secure solution, you can easily add logic to match on the last two presented tokens instead.